# Webform submission redirect to view it come from

Tags: webform-civicrm

I have a view of player's grading record using custom fields set in civi. It's a table with current grade, previous grade, dates, etc.

I've created a form that allows adding extra rows into that view.

I'm trying to create a redirection URL on the webform that after submission will go back to that view with contact id in it's argument.

Not sure how to do that :-(((

Any help appreciated.

Comment: first question - do you have the Contact ID checked to be a webform component - if not, add it, then in the 'redirect' section of Adv Settings you should be able to set the  token for that component as part of the path to get them back to the view

Comment: Hi Peter, I can see the token, it looks like this [submission:contact-id:?], but I'm not sure if I'm to replace "?" with something, remove all together or what?

Answer (score 3):

I've got it finally, I should have copied the token from the actual field, which in my case was "submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_fieldset_fieldset:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_contact_id:nolabel]" and not the example from the token's help window.
Happy days!

Comment: Excellent - thanks for getting back and posting your solution!